# Display of Malayalam symbol changes when the selection changes

Tags: winapi, unicode, richedit

When I move the selection, character spacing and characters themselves change.

Test project code:

```html
#include <windows.h>
#include <Richedit.h>

class RichEditLib
{
    HMODULE lib;
public:
    RichEditLib()
    {
        lib = ::LoadLibrary(L"riched20.dll");
    }

    ~RichEditLib()
    {
        if (lib) ::FreeLibrary(lib);
    }
} libraryLoader;

class RichEdit
{
public:
    RichEdit(HWND parent)
    {
        hwnd = ::CreateWindowEx (
            NULL,    // extended window style
            RICHEDIT_CLASSW,   // name of a registered window class
            L"",      // window caption
            WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_TABSTOP |
            WS_VSCROLL | ES_LEFT |ES_MULTILINE | ES_WANTRETURN | ES_AUTOVSCROLL,     // window style
            0,    // x  position
            0,    // y  position
            400,    // width
            400,    // height
            parent,    // handle to owner window
            NULL,    // handle to menu
            ::GetModuleHandle(NULL), // application instance
            NULL);
        ::ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    }

    ~RichEdit()
    {
        if (hwnd) ::DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    }

private:
    HWND hwnd;
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        ::PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return ::DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;

}

HWND CreateMainWindow(HINSTANCE hInst, int CmdShow,
                      LRESULT (WINAPI *pWndProc) (HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM))
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = pWndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.hIcon = ::LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = ::LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) ::GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WndClass";
    wc.hIconSm = ::LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    ::RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    HWND hWnd = ::CreateWindow(L"WndClass", L"", 
                             WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
                             100, 100,
                             500, 500, 
                             NULL, (HMENU) NULL, hInst, NULL);

    ::ShowWindow(hWnd, CmdShow);

    return hWnd;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND parent = CreateMainWindow(hInstance, nCmdShow, WndProc);
    RichEdit re(parent);

    MSG msg;
    while (::GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
        ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Text:

യൗവനം നശിക്കാത്തവനു മാത്രമേ സുന്ദരികളുടേയും സുന്ദരന്മാരുടേയും കഥ പറയാനാകൂ. പി.സി കുട്ടികൃഷ്ണന്‍ ആ ഗണത്തില്‍പ്പെടും. അതുകൊണ്ടാവും അദ്ദേഹം യൗവനം നശിക്കാത്തവന്‍ എന്നര്‍ത്ഥം വരുന്ന ഉറൂബ് എന്ന പേര് തൂലികാനാമമായി സ്വീകരിച്ചത്.
'സുന്ദരികളും സുന്ദരന്മാരും'-ഇതിഹാസസമൃദ്ധിയുള്ള ആ ഒറ്റ നോവല്‍ മതിയല്ലോ ഉറൂബിനെ മലയാളി നിത്യവും ഓര്‍മ്മിക്കാന്‍. 1920-കളിലെ ഖിലാഫത്ത് പ്രസ്ഥാനം, ദേശീയ സ്വാതന്ത്ര്യ സമരം, മലബാര്‍ കലാപം, കമ്മ്യൂണിസ്റ്റ് മുന്നേറ്റം, രണ്ടാം ലോകമഹായുദ്ധം തുടങ്ങിയവയുടെ പശ്ചാത്തലത്തില്‍ മലബാര്‍ കേന്ദ്രമാക്കി നിരവധി വ്യക്തികളുടെ ജീവിതങ്ങളിലൂടെ രാഷ്ട്രീയ-സാമൂഹിക-കുടുംബ ബന്ധങ്ങളില്‍വന്ന വമ്പിച്ച മാറ്റങ്ങള്‍ അവതരിപ്പിക്കുന്ന നോവലാണ് 'സുന്ദരികളും സുന്ദരന്മാരും'. ഉമ്മാച്ചു, അണിയറ, മിണ്ടാപ്പെണ്ണ്, അമ്മിണി, ആമിന, തേന്മുള്ളുകള്‍ എന്നീ നോവലുകളും 'രാച്ചിയമ്മ'യും 'ഗോപാലന്‍നായരുടെ താടി'യും പോലുള്ള സുന്ദരങ്ങളായ നിരവധി ചെറുകഥകളും ഉറൂബ് മലയാളത്തിനു നല്കി. നാടകം, കവിത, ഉപന്യാസം എന്നീ മേഖലകളിലും ഉറൂബിന്റെ സംഭാവനകളുണ്ട്.

Any ideas what it can be?

Comment: What does `RICHEDIT_CLASSW` expand to? Try replacing it with `L"RichEdit50W"`. If this has no effect we can try some other ideas.

Comment: Thank you! It seems what in version 4.1 this bug was fixed.